# Adding Control to worksheet causes "Can't execute code in break mode"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to add a checkbox to my worksheet using code:

```
Sub DropCheckboxOnSheet()
   ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1"
End Sub
```

When I run this code, I do get a checkbox added to the worksheet, however I also receive the message that Excel "Can't execute code in break mode". I get that my code adds an object to the object model and that this is why it breaks, but it also offeres me the option of continuing.

**How do I tell VBA to continue after adding the object?**

What i've tried:
Adding `DisplayAlerts=False` does not work.
MSDN offers no help either:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264133.aspx

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: now i feel like an idiot. please put as answer so i can mark it as such.

Comment: That code doesn't cause VBA to enter break-mode. Something else is going on.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right! I had the code directly on the worksheet, not in a module. Worksfine if i put it in a module.

Comment: @rohrl77 That's odd, it works for me in a worksheet module just as well. Sometimes bug-conditions can be very hard to track down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the safest solution but you will not get a error since adding "End" kills all macros. The only time i ever really use it is on progressbars. I would dig harder on the real issue using "On error resume next" is a bandaid. If you do use it make sure to restore your default error handling with "On error goto 0".

```
Sub DropCheckboxOnSheet()
   ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1"
 End
End Sub
```

e.g.

```
Sub DropCheckboxOnSheet()
 On error resume next
   ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1"
 On error goto 0
End Sub
```

Changing the name of the sub might fix your issue.  If you have the same sub in another open workbook it could be throwing the error.

Comment: I had the code in a fresh workbook with nothing else in it. It was really baffling me. The one thing I had not tried was the logical on error resume next. since neither John or Jordan opted to put an answer i'll accept yours. cheers.

Comment: FYI: I just tested your first statement... the one with just End.... that didn't work. I need the On Error Resume Next.